# Programmatically set constraints with between multiple same views

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a `constraintLayout` that contains multiple `nodeView`'s. A `nodeView` is a `ImageView` line attached to the left side of a `ImageView` circle [image: node]

I now want to connect X amount of nodes together. To programmatically set constraints, you use the `R.id`, but since I'm connecting multiple same nodes together, and they all share the same `R.id`, this isn't working. Is there any way to reference a specific view's `ImageView` as a reference for setting a constraint for another `ImageView`? I'm starting to think I'm approaching this the wrong way entirely. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the rest of the code.

node code

```
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String description, boolean active, boolean base) {
        View inflatedView = inflate(context, R.layout.tracking_node, this);
        nodeLine = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.imageNodeLine);
        nodeImage = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.imageNode);
        nodeText = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textNode);

        nodeLine.setId(View.generateViewId());
        nodeImage.setId(View.generateViewId());

        nodeText.setText(description);
        if (active){
            nodeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_green);
            nodeLine.setImageResource(R.color.support_success);
        }else{
            nodeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_grey);
            nodeImage.setImageResource(R.color.grey);
        }

        //Remove left-side connecting line if base node
        if (base){
            nodeLine.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
            nodeLine.setImageResource(R.color.transparent);
        }
    }

    public int getNodeImageId(){
        return nodeImage.getId();
    }

    public int getNodeLineId(){
        return nodeLine.getId();
    }
```

constraintLayout code

```
private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        View inflatedView = inflate(context, R.layout.delivery_status_view, this);
        deliveryTrackerView = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutDeliveryTracking);
        shippingDetailsButton = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btnShippingDetails);


        //steps[] is a string array that contains the content of each node
        DeliveryNodeView node = new DeliveryNodeView(context, attrs, steps[0], true, true);
        //Saves resource ID of last node image
        int pastNodeID = node.getNodeImageId();

        //Generates nodes
        for (int i = 1; i < steps.length; i++){

            boolean active = ((i + 1) / currentStep) <= 1;
            node = new DeliveryNodeView(context, attrs, steps[i], active, false);
            int nodeLineID = node.getNodeLineId();


            ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
            constraintSet.clone(deliveryTrackerView);


            deliveryTrackerView.addView(node);
            constraintSet.connect(nodeLineID, ConstraintSet.START, pastNodeID, ConstraintSet.END);
            pastNodeID = node.getNodeImageId();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to set id's to child programmatically before creating constraints among views.

Comment: While initializing the node, I do `nodeLine.setId(View.generateViewId())` and `nodeImage.setId(View.generateViewId())`. The view class also has a `getNodeImageId` and `getNodeLineId` method that returns those ids.

Where I'm handling the `constraintLayout` I run `constraintSet.connect(nodeLineID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, pastNodeID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);` however, the nodes are still stacked on top of each other like they were if they all still shared the same `R.id`. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the entire code you are asking about.

Comment: I've updated the original question.

Comment: What is the supertype of the node class? LinearLayout?

Comment: It's a `ConstraintLayout` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. Here is some sample code that builds a 5x5 colored box array that looks like this:

[image]

The comments in the code outline the key steps. *activity_main.xml* is just an empty *ConstraintLayout*.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        int colorCounter = 0;
        int idToTop = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
        int idToTopSide = ConstraintSet.TOP;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int idToLeft = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
            int idToLeftSide = ConstraintSet.START;
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                View box = getBox(colorCounter++ % 2 == 0);
                // Add the view before getting the ConstraintSet.
                layout.addView(box);
                ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
                cs.clone(layout);
                // Must constrain the view horizontally...
                cs.connect(box.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, idToLeft, idToLeftSide);
                //... and vertically.
                cs.connect(box.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, idToTop, idToTopSide);
                idToLeft = box.getId();
                idToLeftSide = ConstraintSet.END;
                // Apply the ConstraintSet to the layout.
                cs.applyTo(layout);
            }
            idToTop = idToLeft;
            idToTopSide = ConstraintSet.BOTTOM;
        }
    }

    private View getBox(boolean isRed) {
        View view = new View(this);
        view.setId(View.generateViewId());
        view.setBackgroundColor((isRed) ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Alternate code with the same result that separates out the view creation from making of the *ConstraintSet* connections. This *may* be a little more efficient.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        int colorCounter = 0;

        int[][] connections = new int[5][5];
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                View box = getBox(colorCounter++ % 2 == 0);
                // Add the view before getting the ConstraintSet.
                layout.addView(box);
                connections[row][col] = box.getId();
            }
        }

        int idToTop = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
        int idToTopSide = ConstraintSet.TOP;
        ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
        cs.clone(layout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cs.connect(connections[i][0], ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
            cs.connect(connections[i][0], ConstraintSet.TOP, idToTop, idToTopSide);
            for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
                // Must constrain the view horizontally...
                cs.connect(connections[i][j], ConstraintSet.START, connections[i][j - 1], ConstraintSet.END);
                //... and vertically.
                cs.connect(connections[i][j], ConstraintSet.TOP, idToTop, idToTopSide);
                // Apply the ConstraintSet to the layout.
            }
            idToTop = connections[i][0];
            idToTopSide = ConstraintSet.BOTTOM;
        }
        cs.applyTo(layout);
    }

    private View getBox(boolean isRed) {
        View view = new View(this);
        view.setId(View.generateViewId());
        view.setBackgroundColor((isRed) ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked correctly for constraints set between node objects, but when I tried to use it to set constraints between `ImageView`s inside of the node objects, ex: a node line's `START` connecting to the previous node circle's `END`, they still stacked on top of each other. `cs.connect(lineConnections[i], ConstraintSet.START, nodeConnections[i-1], ConstraintSet.END);` where `lineConnections` are the unique ids of every line `ImageView` and `nodeConnections` are the unique ids of every node `ImageView`.

Comment: @WillNasby I see that your comment to Ben P. was that the node object is itself a _ConstraintLayout_. If you are trying to connect a view within one _ConstraintLayout_ to a view in another _ConstraintLayout_, it won't work. Connections must be made within a single, containing _ConstraintLayout_. Is that the case?

Comment: I changed the node object to be a `LinearLayout` and it has the same issues. At this point I'm just going to create the whole linked list programmatically. Won't be as reusable or pretty but I know it'll work.